# Connecting to Google CloudSql with Google AppScript returns "Failed to establish a database connection"

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script, google-cloud-sql

Following the tutorial steps on (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc), a connection still can not be made to their CloudSql, although it has no issues connecting in MySQLWorkbench 6.2.
This is a rough summary of the walk-though which was followed:

1. From the gDevConsole (https://console.developers.google.com/project), Create Project, allows you to set 'Project Name' and 'unique-Project-ID'.
2. Under Storage on left hand side, Cloud SQL, allows you to set instIDSuffix, your full instance id is unique-Project-ID:instIDSuffix.
3. Under Access Control, a Google IP address can be assigned to you, 'x.x.x.y', you then set 'rootPassword', and enter the 10 CIDR ranges under Authorized Networks for Google's AppScript to be able to connect.
4. In appScripts ('script.google.com/... your_document_url'):

   `var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.y/unique-Project-ID:instIDSuffix';
   var root = 'root';
   var rootPwd = 'rootPassword';
   var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, root, rootPwd);
   //Returns this error:
   //Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.`

Is there extra permission necessary? Attempted replacing 'getConnection(...)' with 'getCloudSqlConnection(...)' which returns as an error "Connection URL uses an unsupported JDBC protocol. " Also tried 'unique-Project-ID' and 'instIDSuffix' alone as the end of the dbUrl string.

Answer (score 0):

You state you are using the unique project id, not the database name; you need to specify the db name,add the assigned IP address to create the url, not the project id.  Your dbUrl should look like this (assuming your db name is mynewdb and your assigned IP address is179.156.201.113) : `jdbc:mysql://179.156.201.113/mynewdb`

Comment: Going to https://console.developers.google.com/project/unique-Project-id/sql/instances, you get the image linked to below. The instance id is unique-Project-id:instIDSuffix (in the first blacked out column). https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3_ecTJK_Cn9RkxyaElVYzdrVUE/view As far as I could tell, there is no database name. I've also tried 'Project Name').

Comment: As an update, I found a database must manually be created (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) using   `CREATE DATABASE dbName;` From gAppScript, 'it is `jdbc:mysql:x.x.x.y/` then the the mysql command.